# PHP convert json string to decoded string without backslashes in url JSBeautifer conversion

Tags: php, json

I've got a JSON encoded string that contains an array of objects. I need to preserve the formatting in my front-end without it becoming one long string, right now the output looks like:

```
[
    {
        "url": "http:\/\/example.com",
        "duration": 5,
        "loaded_at": "2021-08-02 15:37:12"
    },
    {
        "url": "http:\/\/example.com",
        "duration": 5,
        "loaded_at": "2021-08-02 15:37:12"
    }
]
```

I need to remove the backslashes from the URL of each object in the array. I'm using the PHP conversion of [JSBeautifer](https://github.com/Wakanda/Beautifier/blob/master/jsbeautifier.org/php/jsbeautifier.php) and it doesn't seem to contain an option to remove backslashes which looks like this in my php file:

```html
<?php
  require_once(ROOT.'/app/Vendor/JSBeautifier.php');
?>

<div class="beautify mb-0">
  <pre><code><?php echo json_beautify(stripslashes($hop['RedirectHop']['journey_json'])) ?></code></pre>
</div>
```

I've also tried utilising the `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` feature in my backend in my controller looping over each item that contains `journey_json`:

```php
foreach ($hops as $key => $hop) {
  $hops[$key]['RedirectHop']['journey_json'] = json_encode($hop['RedirectHop']['journey_json'], JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
}
```

But this gives me in my front-end:

```
"[{\"url\":\"http:\\\/\\\/example.com\\",\"duration\":5,\"loaded_at\":\"2021-08-02 15:37:12\"},{\"url\":\"http:\\\/\\\/example.com\\",\"duration\":5,\"loaded_at\":\"2021-08-02 15:37:12\"}]"
```

I just need the following:

```
[
    {
        "url": "http://example.com",
        "duration": 5,
        "loaded_at": "2021-08-02 15:37:12"
    },
    {
        "url": "http://example.com",
        "duration": 5,
        "loaded_at": "2021-08-02 15:37:12"
    }
]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The backslashes aren't *incorrect*. It's exactly the same with or without them. If you don't want them for some aesthetic reason, you need to `json_decode` the JSON and then `json_encode` it again with the `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` option, otherwise you're double-encoding the JSON.

Comment: do not abuse of these functions and use them only if you are forced yo use them, these functions are slowest and if you have alternatives methods USE THEM. anyway anything around composer/symphony/laravel and most of cms are slowest solutions (if you can build first a library and in time combining classes build your framework of usual actions you need in web production)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I can just do:

```
stripslashes(json_beautify($hop['RedirectHop']['journey_json']))
```

when used with the beautifer